# Is it possible to insert two text fields in one row inside a UIAlertController

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uialertview, uialertcontroller

I'm trying to put two text fields in one row inside a UIAlertController (formerly UIAlertView) in order to create a phone number inputs - one for the country code and one for the number (I need them separated). Is it possible to do this? Answers in swift will be appreciated. :)

[image: That is what I want to achieve]

Comment: UIAlertView is deprecated in iOS 8.0 and Apple has since introduced UIAlertController. It would be better to create your own custom view than hacking UIAlertView which may break in future iOS versions.

Comment: I know that UIAlertView is deprecated. I'm actually using UIAlertController. My mistake.

Comment: @Hayley Guillou - Excuse me, but can you tell me if "U" is a vowel or not? Something tells me that your correction might be wrong.

Comment: "A" goes before the "yoo" sound, like a unicorn, a UFO, a user, etc. http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/a-versus-an?page=all

Comment: Well, excuse my poor English, then! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So this is my piece of Swift code. It works for me. I hope it will work for somebody else too.

```
class NumbersViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

var codeTextField: UITextField?;
var numberTextField: UITextField?;

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad();
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.askForNumber();
}



func askForNumber(prefix: String = ""){
    var title = "";
    var message = "Enter your mobile number\n\n\n";
    var alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
    alert.modalInPopover = true;

    func handleOk(alertView: UIAlertAction!){

        var code: String = self.codeTextField!.text;
        var number: String = self.numberTextField!.text;

    }

    var inputFrame = CGRectMake(0, 70, 270, 25);
    var inputView: UIView = UIView(frame: inputFrame);

    var prefixFrame = CGRectMake(7, 5, 10, 10);
    var prefixLabel: UILabel = UILabel(frame: prefixFrame);
    prefixLabel.text = "+";

    var codeFrame = CGRectMake(20, 0, 65, 25);
    var countryCodeTextField: UITextField = UITextField(frame: codeFrame);
    countryCodeTextField.placeholder = "Code";
    countryCodeTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.RoundedRect;
    countryCodeTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.DecimalPad;

    var numberFrame = CGRectMake(90, 0, 170, 25);
    var myNumberTextField: UITextField = UITextField(frame: numberFrame);
    myNumberTextField.placeholder = "Number - digits only";
    myNumberTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.RoundedRect;
    myNumberTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.DecimalPad;

    self.codeTextField = countryCodeTextField;
    self.numberTextField = myNumberTextField;

    inputView.addSubview(prefixLabel);
    inputView.addSubview(self.codeTextField!);
    inputView.addSubview(self.numberTextField!);

    alert.view.addSubview(inputView);


    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler:handleOk));

    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil);

} }
```

Comment: I need an objective c version of this :(

Comment: It should looks like almost the same ... There must be some changes of initialising variables and may be one or two things, but Obj-C is "Read Only" for me .. I cannot write anything using it .. :)

Comment: Hm ... Why don't you wrap my code in a class and use it in your project as a  swift class:

http://pinkstone.co.uk/how-to-use-swift-classes-in-objective-c/

This link explains the process, but you can do some more research how to do it if you like. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think that Apple discourage this approach, but anyway AlertView have addSubview method, so you can create your textfields and add them to the AlertView. 
Remember to get the TextField become first responder.

But again, Apple discourage this approach.

Comment: What approach do they discourage?

Comment: Asking user for number, using UIAlertControler, using UItextField or combination between them?

Comment: Using AlertView with TextFields, but i've found this tooday, maybe you can use it. https://github.com/nmaletm/STAlertView

Comment: I already found a way how to do it ... I just need some free time to publish it, so other people having the same or similar needs don't loose their time trying to discover the hot water :D

Comment: The way it is done on the link you shared is well known ... i needed the fields looks like just like the attached image